# Order form In JS

Tags: javascript, forms

can someone help to make this form in HTML/CSS/JS? 
can't finish with js :( most important part is that choosen foods must be in the textarea [order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y35yl.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us what you've tried. Remember, we're here to help you with existing code not building stuff from scratch

Comment: Please submit your code! What did you try?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ramdariro/full/bZoBjK  I made this (different but idea is same) .